# Apache not sending last chunk of zero length in chunked response to a CGI http post request

Tags: bash, apache, http, cgi, chunked-encoding

I think this is an Apache bug. I found this:

https://grokbase.com/t/apache/bugs/108ht7t086/do-not-reply-bug-49767-new-no-last-chunk-0-after-post-request-on-cgi-script

https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49766

https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49767

I sent a http POST request to this CGI bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e -n "Content-type: text/plain\n\n"

echo hello world!
```

What could be more innocent? I was shocked to see that Apache answers with a chunked response! And that's not all: The response is even faulty! The last chunk of zero length is missing. There is only one chunk.

The returned headers are these:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 13 Oct 2019 12:19:23 GMT
Server: Apache
Upgrade: h2,h2c
Connection: Upgrade, Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/plain
```

Has this bug still not been corrected? According to the bug reports above the "solution" (workaround) is to read all the posted input before outputing anything. When I did this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e -n "Content-type: text/plain\n\n"

input=$(cat)
echo hello world!
```

the final chunk of zero length is present ;). Is this somehow intended behaviour or is it considered a bug? Why don't they fix it? Do I have to read ALL the input to avoid the error or? Anyone here with more info about this issue?